# View the network drives per user

Tags: windows

One of my users lost a connection to a network folder.

It was Z:\Something\Something.

But now the "Z" is used for a  other network connection.

I need to find a way to see which Network drive are connected a X user because it seems one of his coworker has access to that folder, since i don't have access to his login I can't know the path of that folder.

I'm trying to find a command who does that, but i can't find anything, so far the only commands i saw is with the user itself, and i don't have access to that user now.

Any idea of how can i manage to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looking in the registry on their machine.

Assuming they can run registry editor on their machine (you don't have it locked down.

Run regedit

Navigate to the following location:

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\"
```

Look for the list of mapped drives. This list includes currently mounted drives and those mounted at any point in the past.